# Checking for WebRTC connectivity - reliable methods

Tags: network-programming, connection, protocols, webrtc, ports

I have a live video chat application and I use a TURN server which supports STUN/TURN and both UPD/TCP transmission.

Sometimes users can be connected to the network which **blocks** that much ports and protocols that WebRTC connection just **cannot happen** (usually those are corporate networks). I would like to check if a WebRTC connection is possible before users try to connect to each other (actually, perform a **technical check**).

How can I do it? Ideas I have in my head:

1. Try to **download a hosted chunk of data** (audio file, for example) via WebRTC - is it possible and would this be enough to make sure both inbound and outbound connections are open?
2. Use a **TURN server as a host** to make a connection to and see if it fails (have no idea if I can do it or not)
3. Use **Flash to try to download/upload a chunk of data** over specific ports and protocols. May be even using Cirrus. However, I am not sure this test will be accurate from WebRTC prospective.
4. Any other ideas?

*Additional requirement: the checking technique must support Chrome, Opera and Firefox. Preferably also IE/Safari via Temasys plugin.*

*Edition 1 - gathering ICE candidates is a good idea, however, it is not 100% reliable. Once I checked logs in my application and it actually gathered relay ICE candidates, but video/audio transmission failed. Tested on Apprtc as well and got same results.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the typical WebRTC approach to this is to create a peerconnection with STUN and TURN servers, call createOffer and setLocalDescription and watch the candidates gathered. See e.g. http://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/

If you get srflx candidates, your stun server works (i.e. UDP is not blocked). More interesting is whether you get relay candidates. If you do, using TURN as a fallback will work. Quality might suffer if TURN/TCP is used. If you don't get relay candidates... calls are very unlikely to work.

Comment: Are you sure this method is reliable? Please see the Edition 1 to this question.

Comment: it is reliable in telling whether the local client is able to reach out. There is no way to tell if the remote client can do the same in advance.

Comment: A combination of this and the other answer that works well is to actually create two peerconnections with icetransports set to relay, and actually create a data channel through the TURN server back to "yourself" and then pump some messages across it. Checks that you can get relay candidates as well as establishing a relayed data channel.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to check is to connect with just a data channel first. Your users won't notice. If that works then audio and video are almost guaranteed to work. As a bonus, you can use the data channel for signaling for super-fast connecting when your users are ready.

Comment: I have mentioned that I have to check in advance as a part of technical check. Cannot connect to a real user unfortunately.

Comment: @igorpavlov why not? It requires no permission or user interaction. You were willing to download a hunk of data.  How is that different? Please clarify the requirements of this "technical check".