# Detect if WebRTC is being blocked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webrtc, detectrtc

How can I detect in javascript if WebRTC connections are being blocked? In example by an extension such as [WebRTC Leak Prevent](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webrtc-leak-prevent/eiadekoaikejlgdbkbdfeijglgfdalml).

I tried using `DetectRTC.isWebRTCSupported` from the [DetectRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/DetectRTC) library, but it doesn't return false if the extension is active and blocking connections, as it only states if WebRTC is generally supported, and not if it's also not being blocked, I assume.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can to create a dummy webrtc connection between 2 peer connections and see if you can establish a connection and pass a dummy message though data channel.

One neat example is on : https://test.webrtc.org/

You can check `RunConnectivityTest`  function on there in `main.js`. It is pretty much creating a sample peer connection with different parameters ( Host , Relay connection ..etc) . `establishConnection` is

It would be nice to test when extensions are on whether https://test.webrtc.org shows you connection, data channel, port or something else being blocked

Comment: When the WebRTC Leak Prevent extension is active, the host connectivity fails. But as I'm not experienced with WebRTC, I don't know quite how to include that functionality of checking the host connectivity in my code. Any sugestions? Thx for your time.

Comment: you need someone with javascript skills. see the main.js on that page. understand that connecity functionality and adapt to your case. shouldnt be a hard task for someone with javascript skills

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution, although it's not very clean, and I would appreciate if somebody with WebRTC knowledge could confirm it. Anyways, this is how I can check at the moment if the WebRTC Leak Prevent extension will prevent me from making WebRTC calls.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32012128/8075784) answer helped me.

```
function iceCandidateError(e) 
{
    if(e.errorText == 'STUN host lookup received error.')
        console.error('WebRTC is being blocked');
}

function gotDescription(desc) 
{
    rtc.setLocalDescription(desc);
}

function noDescription(error) 
{
    console.error('WebRTC check failed: no description');
}

config = 
{
    iceCandidatePoolSize: "0",
    iceServers: [ { urls: ["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"] } ],
    iceTransportPolicy: "all"
}

const offerOptions = {offerToReceiveAudio: 1};

rtc = new RTCPeerConnection(config);
rtc.onicecandidateerror = iceCandidateError;

rtc.createOffer(
    offerOptions
).then(
    gotDescription,
    noDescription
);
```